# Caching User Specific, Frequently Used Objects in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have a dynamic menu system in my MVC 4 application. The Complete menu object is same for all the Users. So I save it in the application cache, and the cache depend on the data source I take it from.

Now, the menu is dynamic so that it filter out menu items that current user can't visit(unauthorized). But I don't want to run this filter code every time the user request a page. So, my plan is to save it in the Session object. Is there a better way of doing this without using session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective, you shouldn't be caching that filter logic *at all*. What happens if you change a user's permissions whilst they're logged in (e.g. revoke them completely because of some kind of breach), then the revoke won't actually take effect until they log out and try and log in again.

If however you don't often change permissions and security isn't as critical as described above, then merely using the Session would suffice (although I'm a session hater, so personally I'd re-run the logic).

Comment: But how often we change permissions? Caching role detail may be ok in some scenario

Comment: @Murali Good point, added a disclaimer in case changing permissions isn't frequent.

Comment: Yes, you both made good points. I'm in the same boat as you @mattytommo. I hate using Sessions from the experience I got by using them in web forms. Anyways, I'm going to use glimpse to check if there is a massive time difference in running the filter code for all requests and keeping it in a session. I will post my findings here

Comment: okay, it doesn't affect the performance in anyway. And considering @mattytomo's comment, I'm going to run the code for every request. Thanks for the input guys